# Kali linux portable usb installation

Tags: linux, bios, kali-linux, liveusb, portable

So I downloaded Kali Light 64bit and decided to unpack it with rufus on my USB "W". Then I booted up usb W without any problems and did a full install on a USB "Kali". So after finishing the installation I booted to BIOS to select boot device as the USB Kali. But it doesnt boot up, all files are on the usb but I cant boot from usb itself, bcuz I can only boot the linux using grub which was automatically installed on my Win10 C: drive. So my question is : How do I make this USB Kali portable so I can boot up my linux anywhere without having to install grub or anything else.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wait, so you already had a working Kali on your USB drive, then ran the setup from the boot menu and installed Kali on the same drive?

That's not how you're supposed to do it.

You can either boot live Kali from your USB drive (means none of your changes are saved), or configure and use USB persistence (means to create an additional partition where files can be stored persistently).

Here is the official guide to set up USB persistence: 
https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence

Comment: Is the same procedure for kali light amd64?

Comment: yeah, should be

Comment: And NO I didnt install the linux on the same drive I used drive X to install linux on drive Z. From one USB to another using the classical oldf-school installation with time keyboard settings etc..

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't get that USB "W" "Kali" thing.
But still, the way to go for Kali on USB is live+persistence

Comment: Ok thanks for your time and helful information, the OS is running but its pretty slow :( so I guess I will just have to get a new USB or get a laptop and install it on a HDD the old way. (Or keep trying VMWARE since I have a very good desktop)

Comment: Well I just rebooted it after I rebooted it first and it doesnt work anymore, says that the drive is busy then that it doesnt exist im so fed up with this, no more persistent kali linux images. >C ,,,,, IM formatting the usb and ill keep it for something else :(,,, deleting this post

Comment: giving up already? :D
Yeah, you won't have fun with a slow USB drive. I can recommend the Kingston HyperX Savage. But yes, running it in a VM is probably a more convenient solution anyway.

Comment: Yea, Ive spent more than enough on this unfixable problem, I found the thing I wanted, not a live img not a persistent one here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274449/installing-kali-on-a-usb-drive-not-live-usb-or-persistence-partition                  But the instructions are unclear Id be more than happy if someone explained to me.

Comment: have you seen this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAS5sVAV5hg It worked for him. He got the option to install GRUB at 7:02. Did you get this too? I'm not sure what this 7GB NTFS partition in the beginning is good for, though. My Hindi isn't that good.

Comment: No, I surely did not get an option like that. Yes ive seen the video, unfortunately I am not able to do that since I dont have that option. (TBH I was pretty surprised about that T_T)